# .htaccess allow embedding but redirect on direct image load

Tags: image, .htaccess, redirect

Right now I want to redirect users who open up a direct image thats embedded in another site.

livememe does this perfectly by having `http://www.livememe.com/36opcf5.jpg` redirect to `http://www.livememe.com/36opcf5` even though the direct image url is embedded within another site.

Now I'm trying to acomplish the same thing and this is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?reddit.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?tumblr.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?facebook.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mysite.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ 
RewriteRule ^i/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.(jpe?g|JPE?G)$ /r/$1 [R]
```

Now from what I understand is that I'm allowing these websites to embed my images in their site but I'm redirecting them if they access the url directly without being refered.

For example on my site I have images located like this: `http://mysite.com/i/0b1be.JPG`

While the article is located: `http://mysite.com/r/0b1be`

The redirect works but I'm still failing because you can still access the direct image if you followed it from any of the websites allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?(reddit|tumblr|facebook|mysite).com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^i/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.(jpe?g|JPE?G)$ /r/$1 [R]
```

Comment: this breaks all images that i have embedded within my site.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !^(.*)image(.*)$ [NC]
```